# Regex combine more than 1 function

Tags: c#, regex, replace

How can I call 2 functions in my code for one string?

```
public static string ecleaner(string str)
  {
    return Regex.Replace(str, "[éèê]+", "e", RegexOptions.Compiled);
  }

public static string acleaner(string str)
  {
    return Regex.Replace(str, "[áàâ]+", "a", RegexOptions.Compiled);
  }
```

Now I want to check the word "Téèááést" ,after this it should look like Teaest .

Comment: `str = acleaner(ecleaner(str))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate, like this:

```
public static string cleaner(string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, "(?<a>[áàâ]+)|(?<e>[éèê]+)", onMatch, RegexOptions.Compiled);
}

private static string onMatch(Match m)
{
    if (m.Groups["a"].Success)
        return "a";
    if (m.Groups["e"].Success)
        return "e";

    return "";
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
public static string cleaner(string str)
{
    var groups = new[] { "a", "e" };
    return Regex.Replace(str, "(?<a>[áàâ]+)|(?<e>[éèê]+)", m => groups.First(g => m.Groups[g].Success), RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
string str = "Téèááést";
str = ecleaner(str);
str = acleaner(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string ecleaner(this string str)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(str, "[éèê]+", "e", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }

        public static string acleaner(this string str)
        {
           return Regex.Replace(str, "[áàâ]+", "a", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }
    }

    //...

    var result = "Téèááést".ecleaner().acleaner();
```

You could also combine an extension method class with @p.s.w.g's answer, to make things even neater.